# What native function is called when using objects in if statements?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a module that can be used in if statements to check if a certain value is true or false. The idea is that you do something like this:

```
var module = require('nice-module')

if(module) {
  console.log('The rumors are definitely true')
}
```

However, I want the thing to be configurable, in such a way that this is possible:

```
var module = require('nice-module')

module.configure({ theDress: 'blue with black'})

if(module) {
   console.log('The rumors are still true')
} else {
   console.log('Based on this new information you have given the answer is now no')
}
```

I have tried creating an object that overrides the standard `Object.valueOf()` function, so that I can have a regular object with its own functions and properties, but have it call a certain function and return `true` or `false` when used inside of an if statement. It looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  theDress: 'white with gold',

  configure: function(configuration) {
    this.theDress = configuration.theDress
  },

  valueOf: function() {
    return this.theDress === 'white with gold'
  }
}
```

However, big surprise, it doesn't work. I tried swapping `valueOf()` with `toString()` or assigning the same function to both. I tried `console.log()` on the object, which also does not seem to call my function and just gives me the full object, regardless of which implementation I use. Am I doing the override wrong? Does JavaScript not use `valueOf()` when evaluating if something is truthy or falsy?

Comment: I would simply use something more explicit, `module.isValid()`. Javascript does not offer an explicit API for such object truthiness, so you shouldn't try to write code that behaves this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if( anything )` in JavaScript executes the `true` branch if `anything` is defined in the current scope or is otherwise truthy.

You are misusing the `valueOf` function and misunderstanding it purpose.

In the current JavaScript specification ( http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ ) the `valueOf` function is *only* ever invoked by the JavaScript runtime when the abstract operation `OrdinaryToPrimitive`, via `ToPrimitive` is executed, which only happens under a restricted set of circumstances, specifically if you pass an `Object` value to a another bit of code that uses `ToPrimitive`, search the specification for "ToPrimitive" for more information and context.

Answer (score 2):

No function is called, there's no way for a not null object to be falsy.

See [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that translates to true when
>   evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are
>   defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and
>   NaN).

Two solutions come to mind andwould also probably be clearer for the user:

- use a specific function to provide that feature. It
- throw an exception if configuration failed (your use case isn't clear to me)